# Exercício de linguagem C

Tags: c

Crie um programa que leia do teclado seis valores inteiros e em seguida mostre na tela os valores lidos na ordem inversa.
Ordem inversa, não seria do menor para o menor.
Como fazer?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int i, num[6];
   printf("Digite 6 numeros inteiros.\n");
   for(i=0; i<6; i++) {
        printf("Digite o %d valor: ", (i+1));
    scanf("%d", &num[i]);
   }
   system("cls");
   for(i=0; i<6; i++) {

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Não é lição de casa, é do livro.

Comment: Acho que a ordem inversa é o seguinte: Entrada: `1 3 5 7 9` Saída: `9 7 5 3 1`

Comment: Imprima utilizando o for no _array_ de trás para frente: `for(i=5; i>=0; i--){ num[i];`

Answer (score 4):

Minha interpretação de ordem inversa seria o seguinte:

Usuário entra os valores: `1 2 3 4 5 6`
A saída seria: `6 5 4 3 2 1`

O código pode ser assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int i, num[6];
   printf("Digite 6 numeros inteiros.\n");

   for(i=0; i<6; i++) {
    printf("Digite o %d valor: ", (i+1));
    scanf("%d", &num[i]);
   }

   printf("Resultado:\n");
   for(i=5; i>=0; i--) {
    printf("%d\n", num[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: O `printf` do resultado estás a mostrar o `i` quando devias mostrar o `num[i]` :)

Comment: Além disso o segundo `for` deveria ser de `5` até `0` e não de `6` até `1`.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiramente, o seu exemplo não compila, pois falta um `}`. Olhe como ele fica quando devidamente identado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, num[6];
    printf("Digite 6 numeros inteiros.\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("Digite o %d valor: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);
    }
    system("cls");
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
       system("pause");
       return 0;
    }
```

Suponho que você tenha esquecido um `printf` e um `}` antes do `system("pause");`. Assim esse seria o código (imprimindo em ordem direta):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, num[6];
    printf("Digite 6 numeros inteiros.\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("Digite o %d valor: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);
    }
    system("cls");
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("O %d valor eh: ", num[i]);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Você está lendo os 6 números corretamente. Depois, a solução seria simples. Tenho duas alternativas, escolha a que achar melhor.

## Alternativa 1:

Basta imprimir os números na tela em ordem inversa. Para isso, você itera o array (no segundo `for`) em ordem inversa:

```
for (i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
```

## Alternativa 2:

Você itera o array na ordem correta, mas o preenche na ordem inversa:

```
    scanf("%d", &num[5 - i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução recursiva :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void le_imprime(int n);

int main(void) {
    puts("Digite 6 numeros inteiros.");
    le_imprime(6);
    puts("");
    return 0;
}

void le_imprime(int n) {
    int a;
    if (!n) return;
    if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro de leitura.\nPrograma abortado.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    le_imprime(n - 1);
    printf("%d ", a);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Uma solução pornográfica (não mostrar a ninguém):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char**allwaysnull) { int c;
  if( argc == 8 ){ return 0; }
  if( argc == 1 ){ printf("6 numeros inteiros.\n"); return main(2,NULL); }
  scanf("%d",&c);
  main(argc + 1,NULL); 
  printf("%d\n",c);
}
```

Update: por sugestão purista do @pmg, juntei o segundo argumento do main para (fraudulentamente) calar o aviso `-Wmain`. A nova versão continua a ser assumidamente pornográfica.

Comment: A assinatura da função `main` deve ter `0` ou `2` argumentos: `int main(void)` ou `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. Como não usas o `argv` podes usar `NULL` no teu programa: `main(argc + 1, NULL)`.

Comment: @pmg, actualizado.